# dynamic library gcc compilation error

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I have the following code:

```
gcc -Wall -fno-stack-protector -O2 -g -fPIC -c ec.c
pwd
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libec.so.1 -o libec.so.1.0 ec.o /urs/src/soem/ethercat*.o ../soem/nicdrv.o -lc -lpthread

mv libec.so.1.0 /usr/lib/.

cd /usr/lib
ldconfig -v -n
ln -sf libec.so.1.0 libec.so
ln -sf libec.so.1.0 libec.so.1
```

It gives the following error when compiling:

```
/home/ebox/Documents/SVN/Libs/ec
gcc: error: /urs/src/soem/ethercat*.o: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘libec.so.1.0’: No such file or directory
```

I understand there is something wrong with the gcc command, but cannot figure out how to fix this. There are several .o files in the path that start with ethercat*.

How can I get this fixed?

Comment: The message from `gcc` should be pretty clear: It can't find any files named `/urs/src/soem/ethercat*.o`. The other error is because `gcc` can't link to your library, so it doesn't exist. As for *why* it can't find the file, check the spelling of the path again (hint: I doubt you have a directory `/urs`).

Comment: Check if `/urs/src` is `/usr/src`

Comment: there are several .o files in the `/usr/src/soem' path that start with ethercat, therefore I don't understand why it can't find the files.

Comment: I see, that was pretty obvious. I am going to change it to the correct path. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that there are no files that match the pattern `/urs/src/soem/ethercat*.o`.

Note that the first component is `urs`. Probably it should be `usr`.